# Matrix Norm of a Symmetric Matrix

Tags: matrices

A paper is claiming that for any matrices $A,B$ of appropriate dimensions, say $n \times n$, then
$$
\|A^TA-B^TB\|^2 = (\|Ax\|^2-\|Bx\|^2)^2.
$$
where $x$ is the largest eigenvector, $\|x\|=1$, for $A^TA-B^TB$.  Here is how I proceeded: for the LHS,
$$
\|A^TA-B^TB\|^2 = x^T(A^TA-B^TB)^2x
$$
and for the RHS
$$
(\|Ax\|^2-\|Bx\|^2)^2 = [x^T(A^TA-B^TB)x]^2
$$
but these cannot be the same thing.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The LHS is quadratic in $x$, while the RHS is linear in $x$, so they cannot be the same.

Comment: Try testing your claim with a $2 \times 2$ diagonal matrix.

Comment: We know that $||x||_2=1$, I hope this is true because it is the first line of a proof in a paper.

Comment: When you write, "largest eigenvector", do you actually mean "eigenvector for largest eigenvalue"? And if so would that be eigenvalue of largest modulus?

Comment: Yes, I thought largest e-vector was the technical way to say what you just did.

Comment: If it is, it's news to me. Recommend you edit.

Answer (score 1):

That statement is correct if you really mean the operator norm. Let $C = A^TA - B^TB$. The operator norm of a matrix is given by

$$(*)||C||^2 := \sup_{||x||=1} ||Cx||^2$$

Now as $C$ is symmetric, WLOG we assume that $C$ is diagonalized with eigenvalue $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n$ with an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors given by $e_1, \cdots, e_n$. For all $||x||=1$, write $x= x_1 e_1 + \cdots + x_ne_n$, then

$$Cx = \lambda_1 x_1 e_1 + \cdots \lambda_n x_n e_n \Rightarrow ||Cx||^2 = \lambda_1^2 x_1^2 + \cdots \lambda_n^2 x_n^2$$

Note that the supremum in (*) is attained when $x = e_n$ (Let's say $\lambda_n$ is largest), and $||Ce_n||^2 = \lambda_n^2$. On the other hand,

$$\lambda_n^2 = \langle Ce_n, e_n\rangle^2 = (\langle A^TAe_n , e_n \rangle - \langle B^TB e_n, e_n\rangle )^2 = (||Ae_n||^2 - ||Be_n||^2)^2$$

This is the equality you want.